# Verificar contraseña C#

Tags: c#, .net, contraseña

Generando un contraseña quiero verificar que tenga al menos un carácter, un número y un carácter especial. Mi método contrasenaSegura siempre me devuelve 'false' aunque cumpla todos los requisitos.

```
class Contrasenia {
    private const String CRITERIOS_CARACTERES = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private const String CRITERIOS_NUMERICOS = "0123456789";
    private const String CRITERIOS_ESPECIALES = "!\"#$%&'()*+,-./:;=?@[]^_`{|}~";

    public String GenerarContrasena() {
        Char castearEnterosAutogenerados;
        String contrasenaGenerada = "";
        Char[] caracteresExcluidos = { 'á', 'é', 'í', 'ó', 'ú', 'Á', 'É', 'Í', 'Ó', 'Ú', 'ñ', 'Ñ' }; 
        int[] enterosGenerados = new int[8];
        Random numeroEnteroRandom = new Random();

        do {
            for (int contador = 0; contador < enterosGenerados.Length; contador++) {
                enterosGenerados[contador] = numeroEnteroRandom.Next(32, 138); //RANGO IMPRIMIBLES: 126, CON EXCLUIDOS : 138
                if (enterosGenerados[contador] > 126) {
                    enterosGenerados[contador] = numeroEnteroRandom.Next(0, 12);
                    contrasenaGenerada += caracteresExcluidos[enterosGenerados[contador]];
                }
                else {
                    castearEnterosAutogenerados = (Char)enterosGenerados[contador];
                    contrasenaGenerada += castearEnterosAutogenerados;
                }
            }
        } while (ContrasenaSegura(contrasenaGenerada) == false);   
        return (contrasenaGenerada);
    }
    public Boolean ContrasenaSegura(String contraseñaSinVerificar) {
        Boolean cumpleCriterios = false;

        if (contraseñaSinVerificar.Contains(CRITERIOS_CARACTERES)) {
            if (contraseñaSinVerificar.Contains(CRITERIOS_NUMERICOS)) {
                if (contraseñaSinVerificar.Contains(CRITERIOS_ESPECIALES))
                    cumpleCriterios = true;
            }
        }
        return (cumpleCriterios);
    }
}
```

¿Dónde de ubica el error?

Comment: ¿Está seguro que siempre se cumple la condición `if (contraseñaSinVerificar.Contains(CRITERIOS_ESPECIALES))`? - en la línea que seleccioné, use `{ }` para encerrar la línea: `cumpleCriterios = true;`.

Answer (score 1):

Tu mejor aliado en estas situaciones serian las [expresiones regulares](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex?view=netframework-4.7.2) y su metodo [IsMatch](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.ismatch?view=netframework-4.7.2).

`using System.Text.RegularExpressions;`

```
public Boolean ContrasenaSegura(String contraseñaSinVerificar) {
    //letras de la A a la Z, mayusculas y minusculas
    Regex letras = new Regex(@"[a-zA-z]");
    //digitos del 0 al 9
    Regex numeros = new Regex(@"[0-9]");
    //cualquier caracter del conjunto
    Regex caracEsp = new Regex("[!\"#\\$%&'()*+,-./:;=?@\\[\\]^_`{|}~]");

    Boolean cumpleCriterios = false;

    //si no contiene las letras, regresa false
    if(!letras.IsMatch(contraseñaSinVerificar)){
        return false;
    }
    //si no contiene los numeros, regresa false
    if(!numecaracEspros.IsMatch(contraseñaSinVerificar)){
        return false;
    }

    //si no contiene los caracteres especiales, regresa false
    if(!caracEsp.IsMatch(contraseñaSinVerificar)){
        return false;
    }

    //si cumple con todo, regresa true
    return true
}
```

Antes de llegar a `return true;` puedes agregar otras validaciones como por ejemplo que cumpla con un minimo de caracteres.

Comment: Desconocía la existencia de esos métodos, ¿crees que es mejor usar la tabla ascii y después añadir los caracteres que te interesen como hago en mi código o es mejor directamente incluirlos todos en un array?  Muchas gracias

Comment: no entendi muy bien a que te refieres

Answer (score 0):

Aunque la solución de utilizar expresiones regulares es correcta, respondiendo a tu pregunta, creo que el problema lo tienes en este tipo de expresiones:

```
contraseñaSinVerificar.Contains(CRITERIOS_CARACTERES)
```

Lo que comprueba el método `Contains` es si una cadena está dentro de otra, es decir, estás mirando realmente si la cadenas `CRITERIOS_CARACTERES` aparece completa al menos una vez en la cadena `contraseñaSinVerificar`, que normalmente va a ser siempre `false`.

Lo que deberías hacer es comprobar si alguno de los caracteres está dentro de la cadena que estás buscando, algo así:

```
 foreach (char character in contraseñaSinVerificar)
     if (CRITERIOS_CARACTERES.IndexOf(character) >= 0)
         return true;
 return false;
```

Por supuesto, yo lo haría dentro de una función con dos parámetros: la cadena a verificar y la cadena que contiene todos los caracteres y comprobaría para los tres tipos de esta forma:

```
 return ExistsCaracter(ContraseñaSinVerificar, CRITERIOS_CARACTERES) &&
        ExistsCaracter(ContraseñaSinVerificar, CRITERIOS_NUMERICOS) &&
        ExistsCaracter(ContraseñaSinVerificar, CRITERIOS_ESPECIALES);
```

Por supuesto, añade verificaciones del tipo cadena vacía / nula y demás sospechosos habituales.